# For a bounded sequence in a hilbert space, does $\|u_n\|^2 u_n \to \|u_0\|^2u_0$ ？

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, limits-and-convergence

If $\{u_n\}$ is bounded in a real Hilbert space $H$, with inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$, then ${\|u_n\|^2u_n}$ is also bounded.

As there is a weakly converging sub-sequence, we can WLOG assume that $\{\|u_n\|^2u_n\}$ converges weakly to $u_0\in H$.

Is it right that $u_0=\|u\|^2u$ ?  Practically speaking, can we repeatedly choose a sub-sequence of $\{u_n\}$ to obtain $（\|u_n\|^2u_n，v)\rightarrow (\|u\|^2u,v), \, \forall v\in H $?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $u$ is supposed to be the weak limit of the original sequence $u_n$, the answer is not in general.  For example, if $u \neq 0$, then $||u_n||^2u_n \rightharpoonup ||u||^2u$ iff $||u_n||^2/||u||^2 u_n \rightharpoonup u$.  Since $u_n \rightharpoonup u$, this in turn occurs iff $||u_n||^2/||u||^2 \to 1$, which fails in general; the problem is that all we can conclude in general is $||u|| \leq \liminf ||u_n||$ (cf. Fatou's Lemma) but we don't in general have $||u|| = \lim ||u_n||$ (and indeed, $\lim ||u_n||$ need not exist).

Comment: As $\{u_n\}$ is bounded in $H$, that is, $\{\|u_n\|\}$ is bounded in $R^+$, which implies that $\{\|u_n\|\}$ has convergent subsequence $\|u_{n_k}\|→\|u_0\|$ in $R^+$. But $lim\|u_{n_k}\|≠\|u\|.$ Thank your answer.